# How to retry a http request until a condition is met using rxjs

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to retry a http request until some data exists up to 10 times with a delay of 2 seconds between each retry.

```
const $metrics = from(axios(this.getMetrics(session._id, sessionRequest._id, side)));

const res = $metrics.pipe(
  map((val: any) => {
    console.log("VALUE:", val.data.metrics.length);
    if (val.data.metrics.length === 0) {
      throw val;
    }
    return val;
  }),
  retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(2000), take(10))),
).subscribe();
```

I am trying to follow the example in the documentation. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html

1. I create `$metrics` observable from an axios http promise.
2. I use the map operator to check if the response of the http request matches my condition to retry. `val.data.metrics.length === 0`. If it does it throws an error.
3. I retry the http requests up to 10 times with a 10 second delay.

I expect after 3-4 retries for this metrics array to have data, but in my console when i log the response i get the following.

```
VALUE: 0
```

Im not sure if this is even making multiple http requests because the console log only returns one output instead of 10.

**UPDATE**

Ive updated the code to use retryWhen instead of retry, it does a delay of 2 seconds and will only take 10 errors before stopping.

Now i believe the problem is that it only makes 1 http request because the console log only returns a single output.

Comment: put `delay(2000)` after retry and see what happens. As for network call its because of the `from(axios(options));`, what does this exactly do?

Comment: axios is a http client library, its making the http request into an observable

Comment: Does axios already return Observable? Why do you have `from()`?

Comment: from converts the axios promise into an observable

Comment: Also do you see in the network inspector all the requests and their response? Do you see that correct data is getting sent in response?

Comment: yes i am sending the correct request

Comment: Write  `throw 'data empty';` instead of `return throwError('data empty');` when using `retryWhen()`

Comment: ye i already changed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use defer()

```
const $metrics = defer(()=>from(axios(this.getMetrics(session._id, sessionRequest._id, side))))
```

one thing to point out, you should inspect your network tab and see if the request is made in retry. your console.log is in map() operator which will be skipped when error thrown, could be why u don't see console.log there. You can try out the example below.

```
import { timer, interval,from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, retryWhen, delayWhen,delay,take } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit value every 1s
const source = from(fetch('http://kaksfk')).pipe(tap(val => console.log(`fetcching you won't see`)))
const example = source.pipe(
  retryWhen(errors =>
    errors.pipe(
      // log error message
      tap(val => console.log(`retrying`)),
      // restart in 5 seconds
      delay(2000),
      take(5),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This defer did not help, what is it attempting to do here?

Comment: this observable is wrapped in a function that is an async, 

do i need to await anywhere in this observable?

Comment: does axio return a promise ya? `from` already converted that to observable so it should not matter

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: thanks this defer helped but then i have a follow up problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341838/how-to-handle-errors-using-rxjs-and-promises

Comment: `fetch` also needs to be wrapped by `defer`, otherwise, the retry won't work. The reason is that `fetch` returns a promise which has already been rejected.