# How to handle errors using rxjs and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, axios

I am making a http request to a backend api. I have deliberately changed the url to one that returns a 503 so that i can properly handle errors. However **the 503 error response is not being returned here**.

```
const requestOptions = {
  url: "https://httpstat.us//503",
  method: "get",
  // raxConfig: retryConfig,
};

const $metrics = defer(() => from(axios(requestOptions))));

const metrics = await $metrics.pipe(
  map((val: any) => {
    if (val.data.metrics.length === 0) {
      throw val;
    }
    return val;
  }),
  retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(2000), take(10))),
).toPromise();

console.log("metrics", metrics)
```

The console.log at the end returns

> undefined

**I expect to see the response of the http promise which is a 503 status error.**

---

Context: i am using rxjs to handle when to retry the http request. The data might not be ready (length === 0) i retry up to 10 times until data is there. The logic is more complicated inside the map function but i have omitted some of it as its not relevant.

Comment: You can try debugging with `tap` inside retryWhen and check what is logged inside

Comment: Does retry occur 10 times?